# Functions not being triggered on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which is supposed to trigger various functions as I scroll down (each function draws a chart below another). The thing is that this code works well on my screen but when I run it on a bigger screen the functions are not triggered.

I haven't harcoded anything, I have debugged, and tested each conditions and all throw `true`.

This is the troublesome snippet:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($('#chartdiv').html().length != 0) {

    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if (Math.round((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight) === 0) {


      if ($('#chartdiv2').html().length == 0) {
        drawChar2();
      }
      okas.
      else if ($('#chartdiv3').html().length == 0) {
        drawChar3();
      } else if ($('#chartdiv4').html().length == 0) {
        drawChar4();
      } else if ($('#chartdiv5').html().length == 0) {
        drawChar5();
      }
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your screen is very big, you have to add if condition.
Because there is no reason to scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#chartdiv').html().length != 0) {
        var $window = $(window);
        var windowHeight = $window.height();
        var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
        var scrollPosition = windowHeight + $window.scrollTop();
        if (windowHeight === scrollHeight || // add this condition!!!
            Math.round((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight) === 0) {

            if ($('#chartdiv2').html().length == 0) {
                drawChar2();
            } else if ($('#chartdiv3').html().length == 0) {
                drawChar3();
            } else if ($('#chartdiv4').html().length == 0) {
                drawChar4();
            } else if ($('#chartdiv5').html().length == 0) {
                drawChar5();
            }
        }
    }
});
```